# Splitting perl module into multiple files

Tags: perl, module, perl-module

I'm a perl newbie who is working on a module that is getting quite long and I want to split it into multiple files for easier maintainability and organization. Right now it looks something like this

```
#ABC.pm
package ABC;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $var1;
my $var2;

sub func1 {
    #some operations on a $var
}

sub func2 {
    #some operations on a $var
}

return 1;
```

I'd like it to look something like

```
#ABC_Part_1.pm
package ABC;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $var1;
my $var2;

sub func1 {
    #some operations on a $var
}

return 1;
```

---

```
#ABC_Part_2.pm
package ABC;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub func2 {
    #some operations on a $var
}

return 1;
```

The issue I'm having is getting the variables to be seen across the separate files. I tried to declare them using 'our', but then I have to use the scope resolution operator which I don't want to do. I'd like to treat them as local variables within the module files, but have them hidden to the calling script. I'd also like to only have one include in the calling script, like

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#script.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use ABC;

func1();
func2();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> The issue I'm having is getting the variables to be seen across the separate files.

Your best option is to stop wanting that.

The whole point of lexical variables is for them to be accessible in only a small locally visible bit of code. A variable that needs to be accessed from multiple different files is a sign of "code smell".

If you're really sure you want this though…

> I tried to declare them using 'our', but then I have to use the scope resolution operator which I don't want to do.

Yes, this should work, but you need to declare the variable at the top of *each file* you use it in.

```
# ABC_part_1.pm
package ABC;
our $foo;

# code that accesses $foo goes here

1;
```

And then:

```
# ABC_part_2.pm
package ABC;
our $foo;

# code that accesses $foo goes here

1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make your ABC.pm file a collection of `require` statements.

```
package ABC;

require ABC1;
require ABC2;
require ABC3;

1;
```

It's important to work with `require` instead of `use`, because `use` will try to import things automatically. But that will not work since there is no `package ABC1` in your ABC1.pm file, so `ABC1->import` will fail.

Regarding the variables, there's really no way to get lexical variables into different files. You *could* use `do` instead of `require`, which would read and run the files directly in the line with the `do`. That way, the scope would stay the same, and you could have this.

```
package ABC;

my $foo;
my $bar;

do 'lib/ABC1.pm';
do 'lib/ABC2.pm';
```

---

**Please do not do this. It's crazy!**

If you feel that your library is getting too big, first add proper documentation to every function, and sort so that things that belong together are together. If that does not help you, split up the file into smaller logical units and make those individual packages that talk to each other through a defined interface, but also are able to stand alone where needed.

If repeating a bunch of `use` statements feels like too much boiler plate, write your own module collection (like strictures) using [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into).

Furthermore, don't use lexical variables in the file scope. If you want to have state for things, create object oriented code and write classes. Then you'll have state and behavior. If you have package/class data, use package variables.

Perl doesn't have the concept of private things for a reason. There are conventions in place to mark things as private, like naming them `_stuff` with a leading underscore. That's a sign for everyone that this is internal, not a stable API, might change at any moment and shouldn't be messed with. Do that, instead of trying to hide things. It's a strength of Perl to allow you to mess with everything. But that doesn't mean you *have to do it*. It's an option that you should embrace.

Comment: The top part of my answer is the _technically this is possible_ thing. But please, **do not use that**. The second part is what you should be doing. Or if you don't like that, do what Toby is saying.

Comment: @zebramints  This is a lot of really good advice, the second part, and I don't know how to support it enough.  If I had to say _one_ thing, I'd say create separate modules of logically related subs. If that's unsuitable either just nicely organize and document one module or make it a class (or a hierarchy or classes). You _are_ trying to modularize your module, so to say, and variables seen across multiple files work _against that_.